# What do we do now that click toggle has been deprecated?

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, scrolltop

I'm trying to work out what we now do that click toggle has been deprecated?

I'm after something so if you click `.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger` it scrolls 100px down, and if you click again it scrolls 100px up.

```
$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(y+100);
});
$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(y-100);
});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set a flag with a variable or with `data()` to keep track :

```
$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').on('click', function (e) {
    var y      = $(window).scrollTop(),
        scroll = !$(this).data('clicked') ? (y+100) : (y-100);

    $(window).scrollTop(scroll);
    $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ptn2Q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to set the state, a simplified example:

```
var active = false;

$('.wwd-content-container').click(function(e){
    if(!active){
        alert("First click");
        active = true;
    }else{
        alert("Second Click");
        active = false;
    }
});
```

[LIVING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FujBT/)

With your code:

```
var active = false;

$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e){
    if(!active){
        var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        jQuery(window).scrollTop(y+100);

        active = true;
    }else{
        var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        jQuery(window).scrollTop(y-100);

        active = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own replacement like this:

```
$.fn.toggleClick = function() {
    var functions = arguments, iteration = 0;
    return this.click(function() {
        functions[iteration].apply(this, arguments);
        iteration = (iteration + 1) % functions.length;
    });
}
```

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Then you can use it like this, providing an arbitrary number of functions as arguments:

```
$('#mydiv').toggleClick(
  function() { alert("do"); },
  function() { alert("some"); },
  function() { alert("stuff"); }
);
```

In your case, you'd do this:

```
$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').toggleClick(
  function() {
    var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(y+100);
  },
  function() {
    var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(y-100);
  }
);
```